# Как делать запросы с интервалом минимум 2 секунды?

Tags: angular2, angular

```
export class UserService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getUser(username: string): Observable <any>{
    return this.http.get<any>(`https://api.github.com/users/`+ username);
  }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `как сделать чтобы запрос делался (http:githubUser) минимум 2 сек. ` - что это значит?

Comment: На фотке видно что запрос о меня очень быстро делается за 1секунд 10запросов деляется. я хачу чтобы каждый 2секунды делался запрос. Понел?

Comment: Например пишу Артур и чтобы через 2секунды сделался запрос... а тут пока пишу Артур то на Арт и Арту и Артур делается запрос.

Comment: можешь пожалуйста как пример сделать. Я пробую не получается. :(

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно повесить обработчик события `keyup` на ваш DOM элемент с помощью `fromEvent` и использовать соответствующие операторы.

Вы не показали свой шаблон, поэтому я приведу свой маленький пример:

```
<input type="search" #search>
```

В компоненте нам нужно сделать DOM запрос, чтоб получить доступ к `ElementRef` этого узла, а также повесить на него соответствующий обработчик события:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

import { Subject, fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
import { auditTime, pluck, switchMap, takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({ ... })
export class SomeComponent {
  @ViewChild('search')
  public search: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement> = null;

  private readonly destroy$ = new Subject<void>();

  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    fromEvent<KeyboardEvent>(this.search.nativeElement, 'keyup').pipe(
      auditTime(2000),
      pluck<KeyboardEvent, string>('target', 'value'),
      switchMap((username) => this.userService.getUser(username)),
      takeUntil(this.destroy$)
    ).subscribe((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    });
  }

  public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.destroy$.next();
    this.destroy$.complete();
  }
}
```

`auditTime` создает под капотом предикат и использует `setInterval`, обновляя этот предикат, а также генерирует событие после 2 секунд. `pluck` - извлекает свойства из инстанса `KeyboardEvent` (чтобы нам не приходилось писать `event.target.value`). `switchMap` подписывается на `getUser`, но будет делать каждый раз новый запрос, если сервер не ответил, но пришел новый `username`.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/962712/%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-debouncetime-angular7

Comment: зачем вы создали еще 1 вопрос? я же вам показал как сделать задержку, вы сделали неправильно

Comment: @Artur удалите идентичный вопрос который вы создали после этого и пишите сюда в комментариях что у вас не получается, я буду отвечать, ничего смертельного не произойдет :)